# Как очистить массив от нулей при помощи лямбда-выражений?

Tags: c++, c++17, лямбда-выражение

Есть, например, такой массив:

```
enum class T {A, B, C};     // Есть некое перечисление
using TI = map<T, int>;     // Допустим его так можно заюзать в массиве
TI massive = {{A, 1}, {B, 0}, {C, 0}}
```

Как его можно очистить от нулей используя лямбда-выражение?

Чтобы вот это получилось: `{{A, 1}}`.

Например как-нибудь по типу такого:

```
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 };
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [](auto& element){return element == 0;} ), v.end()
);
```

Comment: почему map обзывается массивом?

Comment: Потому что очень на него похоже. Вы так не находите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

enum class T {A, B, C};     
using TI = std::map<T, int>;     
TI massive = {{T::A, 1}, {T::B, 0}, {T::C, 0}};

int main() {
    std::erase_if(massive, [](const auto& item) {
        const auto&[k, v] = item;
        return v == 0;
    });

    for (const auto&[k, v] : massive) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(k) << ' ' << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: @dIm0n,  что то я не вижу в стандартной библиотеке алгоритма std::erase_if. Не подскажете, где его нашли?

Comment: @KoVadim https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if

Comment: Вы не путаете алгоритм и функцию-член класса?

Comment: @KoVadim не понял. Я привёл ссылку на функцию, которая используется у меня в ответе

Comment: Так, я опять параметры попутал. Да, там алгоритм. Но в любом случае, я в соседнем комментарии уже описал, и это 20 стандарт. Не всякий компилятор с наскока пока такое возьмёт.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если ну очень хочется лямбда-выражение - можно и его пришить, хотя проще без него:

```
enum class T {A, B, C}; 
using TI = map<T, int>; 
TI massive = {{T::A, 1}, {T::B, 0}, {T::C, 0}};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(auto it = massive.begin(); it != massive.end(); )
    {
        bool kill = [](auto& elem){return elem.second == 0; }(*it);
        if( kill )
            it = massive.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }
    for(auto m: massive)
        cout << m.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ну через цикл можно и без лямбды. Я думал, что можно как-нибудь более простым выражением обойтись. Просто стало интересно, можно ли как-то применять функции типа *erase()* для сложных объектов.

Comment: можно, подождите 20 стандарта в Вашем компиляторе. там у std::map есть erase_if

Comment: Второй параметр `main` нестандартный. Кстати, эти параметры в коде вроде бы не используются, так что необязательно их приводить

Comment: @dIm0n А что сказать-то хотели?...

Comment: @Harry в каком смысле? То, что написал, то и хотел :) Думаю, стоит исправить ответ

Comment: @dIm0n Отнюдь. Лично я воспринимаю ваш комментарий, как удовлетворение жгучего желания возразить, и так как по сути возразить нечего - начинаете цепляться к тому, к чему можете :)  "An implementation shall allow both
(2.1) — a function of () returning int and
(2.2) — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int" Увы, здесь нет возможности банить других пользователей, как в FB, например...

Comment: @Harry ну, всё правильно, *pointer to pointer to char*, а не *pointer to pointer to const char*

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю мы вросто хотите дернуть лямбду - то наверное так

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <ostream>

template<typename OS, typename T1, typename T2>
OS& operator<< (OS &out, const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) {
  out << p.first << " " << p.second;
  
  return out;
}

int main() {
  std::map<uint64_t, uint64_t> m{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};

  for (auto& p : m) {
    std::cout << p << "; ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  auto f{[](std::map<uint64_t, uint64_t>& m, uint64_t val){std::erase_if(m, [=](const auto& item) {return item.second == val;});}};
  f(m, 0);

  for (auto& p : m) {
    std::cout << p << "; ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<ostream>` не нужен, но нужен `std::uint64_t`